# Encoding error while reopening my android project in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, encoding

The last time when I closed my android studio, after programming. My code was error free and was working perfectly alright.

Today, when I reopened my program. I received error, my file called DataProvider.java was total blank. error said some illegal characters \0000 not allowed.

Upon searching for the error. People suggested to open DataProvider.java in notepad++ or sublime text and save it with UTF-8 encoding without BOM. But no success!

Since after doing that I got an another error, which said

```
Error:(1, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Now, atleast I could see content in my file DataProvider. but all in zero. Something like this

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Could somebody help me out decoding my file and run it properly with my existing project.

Thanks in advance